# Right use of 'Prefer' and 'Despite the fact'

Tags: grammar

Is the following phrase grammatically right? especially the way I use the 'Prefer' and 'Despite the fact that'?

*Despite the fact that I prefer studying drinking french coffee instead of drinking espresso.*

Comment: "Despite the fact that I ..." is perfectly correct, but you may say in a shorter manner "Despite I ...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence has two problems. One is that it has two verbs right next to each other after 'prefer'. When you say 'prefer studying drinking' it means that you prefer to study *drinking*, in other words the coffee-drinking is what you are studying. What you mean to say is:

> Despite the fact that I prefer to drink French coffee instead of
>   espresso when I am studying.

The other problem is that the sentence is incomplete. 'Despite the fact that' implies that something *different* happens even though you prefer French coffee while studying. That other thing is actually the main part of the sentence, and the words you've written are a clause that modifies it. You can put the main sentence before the clause:

> Espresso is my favourite type of coffee, despite the fact that I
>   prefer to drink French coffee instead of espresso while studying.

Or you can put it after the clause:

> Despite the fact that I prefer to drink French coffee instead of
>   espresso while studying, I buy two kilograms of espresso every month.